# How law enforcement agencies catch culprit who uses shared network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, network-shares

We have shared WiFi router, all my roommates use it.
I want know if my any of roommate do some illegal activity (such as downloaded pirated stuff), how law enforcement agencies will catch the culprit ? Because as far as I know, website knows only our public address not private or MAC address.

Comment: You want to know what they are up to?... so you are worried you are missing out on something?

Comment: I want know how secure is this arrangement

Comment: They ask Google.  Google knows everything about everybody.

Comment: So you want to know so you can avoid getting caught doing illegal things...

Answer (score 3):

Whoever’s name is on the account is responsible for the activity of the people using that account.

If your name is on the account, and your “friends” are doing illegal things, then law enforcement will come knocking on your door. At that point, you, and perhaps all your friends will be in trouble.

When they confiscate ALL your computer equipment they will figure out who was doing the illegal activity. Perhaps they will just arrest all of you and throw you all in jail, until you all squeal on each other, if there is any doubt.